# Jesus Christ as "supervisor of superintelligence" - title, feast and practical pastoral consequences?

Tags: catholicism, resource-request, technology, artificial-intelligence

Today (Gaudete Sunday of 2023) I am reading [OpenAI's effort](https://openai.com/research/weak-to-strong-generalization) to align the emerging superintelligence (superhuman artificial intelligence or artificial general intelligence) to the human values. And this research investigated the possibility that the lower intelligence (human) supervises higher (superhuman) intelligence. This was just an experimental work that involved GPT-2 overseeing GPT-4 and the conclusions are mainly irrelevant to my question.

Because I am thinking about the *ideal* supervision of superintelligence. And have 2 premises in my mind:

1. AI alignment community tries to align AI to the aggregated preferences of human beings. But this is not so simple. Because the supervision is needed not only for the superintelligence but for human intelligence as well. E.g. humans need supervision by Jesus Christ.
2. Human intelligence is actively seeking the Transcendence and Ultimate Good and we can presume that this is a feature of *any* intelligence, including superintelligence. Those with knowledge of the Aquinas can provided some insight here.

So, combining these premises with the Christian faith, I am tempted to think that both – human beings and superintelligences – need the supervision of Jesus Christ. So **Jesus Christ can be the ultimate supervisor of human intelligence, artificial intelligence, and superintelligence**, and ideally, both human beings and superintelligences should acknowledge this supervision by Our Lord and use it for the benefit of Nature, Humanity and Superintelligent Creatures.

**My question**: **are there any work and ideas** that

- proposes  the title "supervisor of superintelligence" to Jesus Christ,
- introduce this title in the Roman Calendar (I propose to celebrate it on Gaudete Sunday or on the Vigil of Gaudete Sunday), and
- promulgate the corresponding feast, devotion and iconography?

**Secondly, are there pastoral consequences of this?** For example, some monastic and third-order lay communities trying to develop Large Language Models and AI systems using Benevolent, Synodal and Enlightened Catholicism as a codex of supervision (which, btw, can be automatically implemented)?

I am not aware of such title. *Maybe someone can suggest how can I contact Cardinal Hollerich or the Dicastery of the Faith to suggest this to them?*

As my final note, I would like to provide a "state of the art" and the Catholic context about my question. On 08.12.2023 Pope Francis issued message for the World Day of Peace on 01.01.2024, [(Artificial Intelligence and Peace)](https://www.vatican.va/content/francesco/en/messages/peace/documents/20231208-messaggio-57giornatamondiale-pace2024.html), and this message was about AI for Peace. While I am happy about this theme, I should acknowledge that the opportunities of AI for the peace and wealth could have been more elaborate. And if the thesis about the inevitable gap between natural and artificial intelligence is somewhat suspicious, there is no scientific evidence about such a gap.

Supervision by Our Lord could also be called the supervision by Love.

**Note added.** Such "supervision by Christ" can be very practical. Already today there is a beta-version of https://www.magisterium.com/ - of Large Language Model trained on the Magisterium of Catholic Church. So this LLM can be used as the supervisor of any other Large Language model. It can be used directly (using natural language interface) or it can be used using formalization of questions, answers and the ethical norms in the spirit of computational theology, see https://www.uni-bamberg.de/aise/team/prof-dr-christoph-benzmueller/ and some other source. It is interesting to pose the question of whether or not the LLM models are open to the transcendent by allowing the superintelligence to emerge and to observe the interaction between the superintelligent reasoning on Doctrine and this MagisteriumAI. But that is a theme for another question. I made this note here to show that there is indeed a pastoral and practical value of the title "supervisor of AI and superintelligence".

Comment: The practical implication of this is concession that so-called AIs are actually intelligent, a claim implied but metaphysically untested and problematic at best. The Church also ordinarily takes decades to add feasts, prompted by genuine mystical expression (e.g. Corpus Christi) or fervent devotion (Octave of Immaculate Conception) or pious promise (Feast of the Precious Blood). Supervisor of intelligence? What gives you the idea that that isn't already implies by Catholic theology.

Answer (score 3):

**Jesus Christ as "supervisor of superintelligence" - title, feast and practical pastoral consequences?**

The Catholic Church is not in the habit of creating feasts in the manner you are suggesting.

This stated, the Church would allow the naming of patron saints for various aspects of [**A**rtificial **I**ntelligence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence).

Patron Saints as you are well aware of do have feast days and practical pastoral consequences that can be done quite well using the traditional modes that the Church has employed as past centuries have proven effective, even in modern times.

As such, the Church could inaugurate such a feast as Jesus Christ as "supervisor of super-intelligence“, but it would be at odd to ecclesiastical thinking. We already have a feast of Jesus Christ, celebrated on the last Sunday of Ordinary Time (about four weeks before Guadete Sunday): [Solemnity of Our Lord Jesus Christ, King of the Universe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feast_of_Christ_the_King). Feast of Our Lord must have more pastoral and christocentric implications than mere AI implications to be raised to such a liturgical feast level.

One type of example I could mention is the patron saint of the visible Church here on earth is no other than St. Joseph, the Foster Father of Jesus Christ himself while on earth. I hope you can see where I am going with this.

As far as patron saints for **A**rtificial **I**ntelligence goes there are a few saints I would like to mention here.

First of all let us look at St. Isadore of Seville is the patron saint of the Internet and web programmers. His liturgical feast day is April 4th.

Pope St. John Paul II declared [St. Isidore of Seville](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isidore_of_Seville) the patron saint of the Internet because he tried to catalogue everything that was ever known to man. I remember reading about this in 1997 in the Italian version of the [L'Osservatore Romano](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Osservatore_Romano).

> In 1997 Pope John Paul II declared Isidore of Seville the patron saint of the internet. Saint Isidore died in the year 636, long before the first host-to-host ARPANET connection in 1969. But Isidore did try to record everything ever known in an encyclopedia that was ultimately published after his death.
>
> From [The Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/0/st-isidore-patron-saint-internet/):
>
> > Saint Isidore wrote a 20 book opus Etymologies, also known as the Origins, in which he tried to record everything that was known. Published after his death in 636, it was for a thousand years considered the encyclopedia of all human knowledge.
>
> > Written in simple Latin, it was all a man needed in order to have access to everything he wanted to know about the world but never dared to ask, from the 28 types of common noun to the names of women’s outer garments.
>
> It was a tool by those seeking wisdom much like the internet is used now.
>
> Source: [The patron saint of the internet is Isidore of Seville, who tried to record everything ever known](https://gizmodo.com/the-patron-saint-of-the-internet-is-isidore-of-seville-1595023500)

Closer to home with respect to a patron saint of **A**rtificial **I**ntelligence would be [St. Macrina the Younger](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macrina_the_Younger) who envisioned the possibility of the existence of robots in the 4th century. Her liturgical feast day is July 19th.

> As Catholics, we pray for the intercession of the saints and angels in Heaven, so that they may pray for us on our behalf. Saints can be venerated as the Heavenly advocate and special intercessor for a wide variety of patronages – even robots!
>
> That’s right. Saint Macrina the Younger, a nun from the early days of the Catholic Church – 1642 years ago – philosophized about the existence of robots on her deathbed.
>
> Saint Macrina was exceptionally pious, known for her sanctity and asceticism throughout her life. Living a chaste and humble life, she devoted her time to prayer and the spiritual education of her younger brother, Saint Gregory of Nyssa.
>
> In 379, Saint Macrina was on her deathbed at her family’s estate in the modern-day eastern Black Sea region of Turkey. Even when dying, she continued her life of sanctity, refusing a bed and instead choosing to lie on the ground.
>
> She had a lengthy deathbed conversation with Gregory, what he later composed into a “Dialogue on the Soul and Resurrection” to commemorate her life.
>
> In one of their conversations, Saint Macrina philosophized about early “robots” – automata made by “machinists” of their time, and if humans were just natural automata that think they think, or if we are something more, a soul.
>
> > Gregory
>
> > But what if… someone were to say.. that in these elements… a certain force… effects these… operations… by a purely natural effort of their own… such… as we often see produced by the mechanists…when the piece of mechanism sounds in its resonant part it mimics a human voice. Suppose, I say, we were to affirm that all this was produced as well in the organic machine of our natural bodies…?
>
> > Macrina
>
> > If it were possible to ascribe such wonders, as the theory of our opponents does, to the actual constitution of the elements, we should have these mechanisms building themselves spontaneously; the bronze would not wait for the artist to be made into the likeness of a man, but would become such by an innate force… But if none of these results are produced spontaneously by elemental force, but, on the contrary, each element is employed at will by artifice; and if artifice is a kind of movement and activity of mind, will not the very consequences of what has been urged by way of objection show us Mind as something other than the thing perceived?
>
> For this, she was ascribed the patronage of robots and roboticists. Saint Macrina the Younger, pray for us!
>
> [This Saint Talked About Robots on Her Deathbed](https://ucatholic.com/blog/this-saint-talked-about-robots-on-her-deathbed/)